# What is the use of encapsulation parameter in component portion in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]Kindly explain the `encapsulation` parameter in an Angular 2. when I add this parameter I have some error message. how can I remove it?

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'app-add',
      templateUrl: './add.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./add.component.css'],
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Comment: *when i add this parameter i have some error message*: doing "some" change? How about telling us **which** error message you get, and posting a minimal complete example reproducing the issue? And if you don't know what encapsulation is for, why are you messing up with it?

Comment: i do this still i have get the error.

Comment: wait i will post my error message also.

Comment: Post the error **as text**. Not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly import this library and also check in this library on you node_module file.

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: i have generate my file in command line interface it will import all the file from the node_module when it also import the some basic class in the ts file when why this file does not import my file.